# Problem programming with dplyr - error saying object not found in one part of pipe but working earlier

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, r-highcharter

I have a working function with and `if else` that was largely duplicated code, so I'm trying to get rid of the duplication by using an in line if else statement.  What's strange to me is that the same snippet works in one place of the code but not in the other.

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

plot_highchart <- function(.data,
                          group_by_variable = TRUE,
                          x_value = "Year", 
                          y_value = "total",
                          .group = service,
                          .stacking = "normal", 
                          chart_type = "column") {
  
    .data %>%
      

      # this next line works.  If you comment out the hchart part it will group by and summarize
      group_by(Year, if (group_by_variable == TRUE) !!rlang::enquo(.group) else NULL) %>%
      summarize(total = sum(Spending)) %>% 

      hchart(chart_type, hcaes(x = !!rlang::ensym(x_value),
                               y = !!rlang::ensym(y_value),
                               group = if (group_by_variable == TRUE) !!rlang::ensym(.group) else NULL))
                               # same bit as before but I get an error

}
```

Here's the error I get when I try to run this:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `group`.
x object 'group_by_variable' not found
i Input `group` is `if (group_by_variable == TRUE) service else NULL`.
```

Which I find strange because `group_by_variable` was found before.  Not really sure where to go from here.

Here's the dput on the data:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), 
    service = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Defense Logistics Agency", 
    "Chemical and Biological Defense Program", "Defense Information Systems Agency", 
    "United States Special Operations Command", "Office of the Secretary Of Defense", 
    "Missile Defense Agency", "Defense Advanced Research Projects Agency", 
    "Navy", "Army", "Air Force"), class = "factor"), Spending = c(0.803, 
    0.628, 0.2, 23.72, 4.782, 12.152)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Hi @BenG. The issue is actually in the same [code block](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/681) as with your other SO question. When `mutate_mapping` calls `parse_quo`, it assigns the expressions to the global environment, which is where it will look for `group_by_variable`. I can show you a workaround, but can you clarify what you want to do when `group_by_variable == FALSE`? You can't pass `group = NULL` to `haes()`, because it explicitly references `group` at some point. Try `hchart( .data, "column", hcaes(x=Year, y=Spending, group=NULL) ); rlang::last_error()` to see where.

Comment: When `group_by_variable == FALSE` I only want it to group by Year and then have some way of not using the group argument in `hcaes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hcaes()` captures the expression you provide to `group` and delays its evaluation. However, the expression undergoes a series of changes in the highcharter package. One of these steps [assigns the global environment to be the evaluation context](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/d47a7792577588d0891dfd87a14a60914371e8c3/R/highcharts-api-add.R#L414), which then causes the R interpreter to look for `group_by_variable` in the global scope, and not in your function where it is defined.

One workaround is to pull the `if` statement outside `haes()`, so `group_by_variable` doesn't get captured by the function as part of the expression to evaluate:

```
plot_highchart <- function(.data,
                          group_by_variable = TRUE,
                          x_value = "Year",
                          y_value = "total",
                          .group = service,
                          .stacking = "normal",
                          chart_type = "column") {

    g <- if (group_by_variable == TRUE) list(group = rlang::ensym(.group))
         else NULL

    .data %>%
        group_by(Year, !!g[[1]]) %>%
        summarize(total = sum(Spending)) %>%
        hchart(chart_type, hcaes(x = !!rlang::ensym(x_value),
                                 y = !!rlang::ensym(y_value),
                                 !!!g))
}

plot_highchart( .data )                             # Works
plot_highchart( .data, group_by_variable=FALSE )    # Also works
```

Here, I am also storing the grouping symbol inside a named list and then using that list with `!!!`. This is necessary to handle the `group_by_variable == FALSE` case, because:

```
hcaes( x = ..., y = ... )                 # Works
hcaes( x = ..., y = ..., group = NULL )   # Doesn't
```

Comment: COOL, thanks.  What's odd is that if I write this out (without the function) and do `group = NA` that will work, but not as part of the in line if else